# using output from CasperJS script in AngularJS app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, casperjs

I have used yeoman.io to create an angular.js single page app which has an app.js to manage routes, some mycontroller.js scripts and an index.html which has a bunch of "bower_components" references for libraries i have installed using "bower install libraryname --save" from the command line.

I also have a casperjs script in a separate file which opens a website, extracts the html and puts the relevant data i want into a json object with some code that looks like this:

```
var casper = require('casper').create){
blah
});

casper.start( url, function(){
blah
});

casper.thenOpen( url, function(){
blah
});

casper.run();
```

The script does what I want when i run it from the command line like this: "casperjs myscript.js".

I ran "npm install casperjs", and this succeeded, but when I used "bower install casperjs --save" it does not add the reference to casper to my index.html file in my app the way it did with jquery-ui for instance. So I manually added it myself by finding where casperjs was installed in "node_modules".

My goal is to get the output of my casperjs script into my angularjs controller, but I'm not sure you can use "require('casper').create" in an angular context, the browser console (and grunt) complain that "require" is undefined, even though I have included the node_modules link to the js file. I am new to angular, and node, and javascript, so I am not sure how they fit together, I have read that you might need to spawn processes to run casperjs, or grab the output from stdout, but I don't really understand what this means, or why I can't just call my casper js as a function from angular.

Has anyone had any experience with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CasperJS is built on top of PhantomJS which is a headless browser. You cannot run CasperJS or PhantomJS scripts directly in the client browser. You can however run them on the server and pass the output through node to the client. Also note that CasperJS and PhantomJS have different runtimes from node.js, so you cannot simply `require` them. You have to use `child_process` for that.

Comment: thanks, done that now. Previously I was running my Angular app for free on Amazon S3. Now that I have a node server, i'm going to need ec2 or heroku, aren't i? I hope it is not a lot more expensive.